# Android show installed app in logcat

Tags: java, android

I want to know installed app list and print logcat. I wrote some code witch can to print installed app list this is a my code

```
public void getInstalledApps() {
    List<PackageInfo> packList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < packList.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo packInfo = packList.get(i);
        if (((packInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) != true) {
            appName = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                    getPackageManager()).toString();
            Log.d("install ", appName);
            installedapps  = appName;
        }

    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), installedapps, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

put on the toast message showing only on installed app. What is a problem? If anyone knows solution please help me. I want to  Assigning  `AppName`  in public string  installedapps

Comment: As per your code, the Toast will always show the last app's name.

Comment: By convention, variable names in Java start with lower case. You are welcome.

Comment: Also how about this method returning a String value instead of setting to a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that each time you are assigning an app name to the variable "installedapps", essentially overwriting the earlier value. What you will end up is the last appname value from the loop.

How about trying the below code. I have only written code additional to what you have written.

```
getInstalledApps(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // your loop
    // your condition
    sb.append(appName).append(" # ");
    // end condition
    // end loop
    installedapps = sb.toString();
    Toast.makeText(.., sb.toString(), 1000);
}
```

You can also try `installedapps = installedapps + appName`, but this is a wrong approach. You should use the [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) approach.

Answer (score 0):

Each time round the loop, you assign `installedapps  = AppName`;

Therefore, when the loop exits, `installedapps` will be equal to the last app.

Try this instead

```
public void getInstalledApps() {
    List<PackageInfo> PackList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < PackList.size(); i++) {

        PackageInfo PackInfo = PackList.get(i);

        if (((PackInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) != true) {
            AppName = PackInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                    getPackageManager()).toString();
            Log.d("install ", AppName);
            sb.append(AppName + "\");
        }

    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

If you don't understand StringBuilder, please Google.